# Как установить лимит на количество записей на странице (пагинация) в GridView Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, gridview, pagination

есть Gridview на странице

```
<?= GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'columns' => [
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
      'id',
      'name',
      'corpusname',
                                
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
      ],
]); ?>
```

и метод в модели собирающий `$dataProvider`

```
public function searchUserCorpusAllocate($params, $userId)
    {
        $query = Company::find()
            ->from(Company::tableName() . ' c')
            ->select('c.id, c.inn as inn, c.name as name,cor.name as corpusname, c.municipality_id')
            ->leftJoin(ExpertCompanyCorpus::tableName() . ' as ec', 'ec.company_id=c.id')
            ->leftJoin(Corpus::tableName() . ' as cor', 'ec.corpus_id=cor.id') 
            ->where('ec.id IS NOT NULL');

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSizeLimit' => 10,
            ],
        ]);

        //pr2($dataProvider);
        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'c.id' => $this->id,
            'ec.user_id' => $userId,
            'c.municipality_id' => $this->municipality_id
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'inn', $this->inn]);

        $names = explode(' ', $this->name);
        foreach ($names as $curName) {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'c.name', $curName]);
        }

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

в настройках `$dataProvider` я добавил

```
'pagination' => [
     'pageSizeLimit' => 10,
 ],
```

но в таблицу все-равно выводится только одна запись.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как вывести все ? и добавить пагинацию?

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination#$pageSize-detail

Comment: Либо укажите `pageSize` (кол-во записей на страницу), либо исправьте `pageSizeLimit` в соответствии с документацией `pageSizeLimit => [minSize, maxSize]`